# SQWRL - Add a new rule

Tags: java, sqwrl

I am new in SQWRL and I have to add a new rule. I know how to execute a query.

My query to add a new rule is :

```
"pizza:Pizza(?p) ^ pizza:hasDiameter(?p, ?d) ^ swrlb:greaterThan(?d, 30) -> pizza:BigPizza(?p)"
```

But I have an error: Invalid SWRL atom predicate 'pizza:BigPizza'. And I don't know how to fix it because BigPizza is the new rule.

:)

Comment: Is `pizza:BigPizza` a concept in your ontology already?